# Is there a cleaner more pythonic way to create class instances within class instances?

Tags: python

I am programming a game with discord py. Each game have 10 players divided into 5 teams.

I don't really need:

- A reference for each player, so the self.BlackHero etc properties are unnecesary...

But I do need:

- Initiate 10 Player instances.
- Initiate 5 Team instances, containing the 10 Player instances.
- A list containing the 12 Player instances.

I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to write the code below? Thanks!

```
class Game:
  def __init__(self, title):
    self.title = title
    self.round = 1
    self.status = 'Registration'
    self.winners = ''
    self.deadline = ''
    self.registrations = {}
    self.chests = []
    self.monsters = []
    
    self.BlackHero = Player('BlackHero.png', 'black-team', 'hero', 'J6')
    self.BlackWitch = Player('BlackWitch.png', 'black-team', 'witch', 'J5')
    self.BlueHero = Player('BlueHero.png', 'blue-team', 'hero', 'A7')
    self.BlueWitch = Player('BlueWitch.png', 'blue-team', 'witch', 'A8')
    self.GreenHero = Player('GreenHero.png', 'green-team', 'hero', 'F9')
    self.GreenWitch = Player('GreenWitch.png', 'green-team', 'witch', 'G9')
    self.RedHero = Player('RedHero.png', 'red-team', 'hero', 'B0')
    self.RedWitch = Player('RedWitch.png', 'red-team', 'witch', 'A0')
    self.YellowHero = Player('YellowHero.png', 'yellow-team', 'hero', 'I0')
    self.YellowWitch = Player('YellowWitch.png', 'yellow-team', 'witch', 'H0')

    self.players = [
      self.BlackHero,
      self.BlackWitch,
      self.BlueHero,
      self.BlueWitch,
      self.GreenHero,
      self.GreenWitch,
      self.RedHero,
      self.RedWitch,
      self.YellowHero,
      self.YellowWitch
    ]
    
    self.teams = {
      'black-team':Team(self.BlackHero, self.BlackWitch),
      'blue-team':Team(self.BlueHero, self.BlueWitch),
      'green-team':Team(self.GreenHero, self.GreenWitch),
      'red-team':Team(self.RedHero, self.RedWitch),
      'yellow-team':Team(self.YellowHero, self.YellowWitch)
    }

class Player:
  def __init__(self, image, team, role, pos):
    self.username = None
    self.user_id = None
    self.image = image
    self.team = team #red/blue/green/yellow/black
    self.role = role #witch/hero
    self.position = pos
    self.new_position = pos
    self.old_target = None
    self.new_target = None
    self.has_sword = False
    self.is_frozen = False
    self.has_moved = False
    self.will_die = False
    self.status = 'ALIVE' #alive/dead

class Team:
  def __init__(self, hero, witch):
    self.hero = hero #username
    self.witch = witch #username
    self.items = []
    self.status = 'ALIVE'
```

It's functional though...

Comment: If it's definitely functional code and it complies with https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - you may want to post this there instead.

Comment: You could almost do this in a couple of simple list comprehensions, but it's not clear how to iteratively generate the `pos` parameter.

Comment: I would keep data in list or dictionary and use `for`-loop to create all `Player()` and append directly in list or dictionary `self.players`

Comment: Consider passing a list of players to `__init__` as an argument, rather than having the game create a list of players. You can added a *class* method that will create the players to pass to `__init__` and return the resulting `Game` instance. (Same for the teams.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. Every `Team` has exactly 2 players, a `hero` and a `witch`, and
2. Every `Game` consists of a number of `Team`s indicated by different colors,

you can considerably simplify your code by adapting the different `__init__` functions
for better integration. E.g., all you need to determine a pair of `hero` and `witch` seems to be

- a shared color and
- a position for each of them.

Assuming they are always part of a team, it makes more sense to initiate the players in the `Team` constructor than in `Game`.

Consider transforming some redundant attributes into something less manual, e.g.,
I assume you manually change `has_moved` somewhere; I'd use a method for that so
you can check if a player moved via `player.has_moved()` or, if you set `@property`
as I did, `player.has_moved` like a regular attribute. Cf. `is_dead` in the `Team`.
I assume you could also check `has_sword` in a similar manner by checking the
`items` of the `Team` or something.

In general, it isn't necessary to initialize each and every possible attribute. E.g., you only
need to set `self.username = None` if someone could try to access
the `username` before it's set, which would throw an `AttributeError`.
If that cannot happen, you can just set the attribute directly when the time
has come to do so (`player.username = 'Carl'`) even
if you didn't initialize it with `None` beforehand.

If `status` is binary (`dead` or `alive`), you might want to change that to
something like `.is_dead` and set it to `True` or `False`.

It's always a good idea to set `__str__` and `__repr__` for easier testing, too.

```py
class Player:
    """
    Represents a Player. Is called by the Team constructor.
    
    color := color string, e.g. 'blue'
    role := 'hero' or 'witch'
    pos := '[A-J][0-9]' e.g. 'B4'
    """
    
    def __init__(self, color, role, pos):
        self.username = None
        self.user_id = None
        self.color = color
        self.position = pos
        self.new_position = pos
        
        # e.g. 'red' and 'hero' -> 'RedHero.png'
        self.image = '{}{}.png'.format(color.title(), role.title())
        self.team = '{}-team'.format(color) #red/blue/green/yellow/black
        self.role = role
        self.old_target = None
        self.new_target = None
        self.has_sword = False # maybe set this as @property method, too?
        self.is_frozen = False
        self.will_die = False

        # maybe set alive/dead as bool, too?
        self.is_dead = False
    
    @property
    def has_moved(self):
        return self.position != self.new_position
    
    # Optional: set string methods
    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{self.color} {self.role}>'.title()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(str(self))


class Team:
    """
    Represents a team of a certain color,
    consisting of a hero and a witch player.

    color := color string, e.g. 'blue'
    positions := Tuple of two positions, strings in the pattern '[A-J][0-9]'
    """
    def __init__(self, color, positions):        
        self.color = color
        self.positions = positions
        self.items = []
        
        roles = ['hero', 'witch']
        
        # initialize and store hero and witch
        for role, pos in zip(roles, positions):
            setattr(self, role, Player(color, role, pos))
            
        self.players = [self.hero, self.witch]

    @property
    def is_dead(self):
        """Returns True if all players are dead"""
        return all(p.is_dead for p in self.players)

    # Optional: set string methods
    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{self.color.title()} Team>'

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(str(self))


class Game:
    """
    Represents a game with teams and players.
    """
    def __init__(self, title, colors):
        self.title = title
        self.colors = colors
        
        # you could also use some smarter heuristic 
        # to determine the positions
        self.positions = [['J6', 'J5'],
                          ['A7', 'A8'],
                          ['F9', 'G9'],
                          ['B0', 'A0'],
                          ['I0', 'H0']]
        self.round = 1
        self.status = 'Registration'
        self.winners = ''
        self.deadline = ''
        self.registrations = {}
        self.chests = []
        self.monsters = []
        
        # Builds teams for each color
        self.teams = [Team(color, pos) for color, pos in zip(self.colors, self.positions)]
        self.players = [p for team in self.teams for p in team.players]
    
    # Optional: set string methods
    def __str__(self):
        return f"<Game '{self.title}' – {len(self.teams)} teams>"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(str(self))
```

A new `Game` is initiated via

```py
Game('Epic match name', ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'])
```

For a lower number of colors, the `positions` are consumed top-down. Adopt to your needs
if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! I'm sure there is a lot of this I can use! I am new to using _str_, _repr_, and @property, so I need to research those a bit more :D

You are exactly right about how I'm manually checking if the Player 'has_moved' and if the Team 'is_dead'. I actually did not know that I could initialize attributes after the instance was created... though I do like to keep an overview of all the possible attributes the object will have in the _init_.